# Sitecore 8.2 Update 1, Using SOLR for both CMS search and Web search

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.2

1. Can SOLR be used for Sitecore search and website search with latest release 8.2.1. the solution needs to be deployed on Cloud
2. Is it required to have Coveo and SOLR both in order to implement search for Sitecore 8.2.1?
3. What is the recommended best practice to use for SOLR search implementation for both CMS and Web search
4. Are there any code samples available?

I have already gone though the following links:
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/configure_a_search_and_indexing_provider

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/setting%20up%20%20maintaining/search%20and%20indexing/walkthrough%20setting%20up%20solr

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, SOLR can be used for both Sitecore and website search. It is recommended to use it over Lucene on distributed environments with multiple CM and CD servers.
2. It is not required to have both SOLR and Coveo. SOLR is enough. However, Coveo is providing features that SOLR doesn't have like UI components that are easy to customize for content editors and marketers, specialized search usage analytics, machine learning, great relevance of search results, multiple languages support... Coveo can only be used for website search. So if you use Coveo, you still need Lucene or SOLR for Sitecore search.
3. With SOLR, it is recommended to create separate Sitecore indexes for your website search needs and leave the default Sitecore indexes there for the Sitecore search. On the SOLR side, those new indexes should be stored in separate SOLR cores.
4. I don't know.